# Composite design pattern and ListBox selection

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have list followed *composite design pattern*. Now I encounter problem how to display it in `ListBox`? My design require that only one `Leaf` can be selected, in entire hierarchy. So far I have:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ILeaf}">
                <Border><TextBlock Text={Binding Name} /></Border>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Composite}">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

So now I have nested `ListBox` each with own `SelectedItem`.

Comment: You probably want to use a TreeView instead.

Comment: Okay, I didn't consider use `TreeView`, because I was sure that it hasn't have `SelectedItem` property. But after check on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx#Events, I was wrong. This solves my problem. There will be a lot styling to do :D

Comment: @Clemens If you find time,write it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked wrong control to display this. `TreeView` fit right.